# How to extract one/two/three adjacent words from a line?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, awk

I want to extract all possible combinations of adjacent words separated by spaces – for one, two, three items. That is, convert this line:

```
a bc de fghi j
```

to

```
a
bc
de
fghi
j
a bc
bc de
de fghi
fghi j
a bc de
bc de fghi
de fghi j
```

How to do this with awk as fast as possible? I'm absolutely stuck and have no idea. I thought about something like `match($0, /^([a-z]+)$|([^\s]+\s[^\s]+)|([^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+)/, arr)` but it can't work in this situation.

**EDIT**
The essential problem is how to combine this with using `split`. For example,

```
{split($0, arr, ",");
for (i = 1; i <= length(arr); i++) {
    print arr[i]
}
for (i = 1; i <= length(arr) - 1; i++) {
    print arr[i] " " arr(i+1)
}
for (i = 1; i <= length(arr) - 2; i++) {
    print arr[i] " " arr[i+1] " " arr[i+2]
}
}
```

gives `Call to undefined function`

Comment: right a script for that. There are many ways to do it. It depends on you what logic you make.
Hint: use array

Comment: You have a typo on line 6. Change `arr(i+1)` to `arr[i+1]`.

Comment: Uh-oh, that was a haste! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat verbose `awk` script that will generate the output based on the input you gave.

```
{
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    print $i
}
for (i = 1; i <= NF - 1; i++) {
    print $i " " $(i+1)
}
for (i = 1; i <= NF - 2; i++) {
    print $i " " $(i+1) " " $(i+2)
}
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f Extract.awk Input.txt
```

Here is a more general version that works for `k > 3` adjacent words.

```
function join(array, start, end, sep, result, i)
{
    if (sep == "")
       sep = " "
    else if (sep == SUBSEP) # magic value
       sep = ""
    result = array[start]
    for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
        result = result sep array[i]
    return result
}

{
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    a[i] = $i    
}
for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
for (i = 1; i <= NF - k; i++) {
   result = join(a, i, i + k, " ") 
   print result
}
}
}
```

Comment: If I'm going to use `split (str, arr, sep)`, can I replace `NF` and `$i` with `length(arr)` and `arr[i]`?

Comment: @lyricallyevil I don't see why not but the only real way to know is to try it :)

Comment: please, check the update. Can you edit your answer assuming `$0 = split ($0, arr, sep)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this perl command using lookahead:

```
s='a bc de fghi j'
perl -ne 'print join "\n" =>$_ =~ /(?=\b(\w+)\b)/g; print "\n";
          print join "\n" =>$_ =~ /(?=\b(\w+\s+\w+)\b)/g; print "\n";
          print join "\n" =>$_ =~ /(?=\b(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\b)/g; print "\n"' <<< "$s"
a
bc
de
fghi
j
a bc
bc de
de fghi
fghi j
a bc de
bc de fghi
de fghi j
```

Comment: Nice... In this case an ordinary comma could be used instead of `=>`